# C# dictionary adding to wrong key/value pair

Tags: c#, arrays, string, dictionary, increment

I have the following foreach loop in my program:

```
Dictionary<string, int[]> summaryDate_clipsEpisodesImps = new Dictionary<string, int[]>();
Dictionary<string, int[]> summaryPartner_clipsEpisodesImps = new Dictionary<string, int[]>();    

foreach (DataRow row1 in dt10.Rows)
{
     int[] numbers = new int[3];
     numbers[0] = 0;
     numbers[1] = 0;
     numbers[2] = 0;

     if (!dictionary1.ContainsKey(row1["value1"].ToString().Trim()))
     {
          dictionary1.Add(row1["value1"].ToString().Trim(), numbers);
     }

     if (!dictionary2.ContainsKey(row1["value2"].ToString().Trim()))
     {
          dictionary2.Add(row1["value2"].ToString().Trim(), numbers);
     }

     if (row1["yes_or_no"].ToString().Trim() == "yes")
     {
          dictionary1[row1["value1"].ToString().Trim()][0] = dictionary1[row1["value1"].ToString().Trim()][0] + Convert.ToInt32(row1["a_number"]);
          dictionary2[row1["value2"].ToString().Trim()][0] = dictionary2[row1["value2"].ToString().Trim()][0] + Convert.ToInt32(row1["a_number"]);
     }
}
```

Essentially, I am looping through a datatable and creating a dictionary of string/int arrays based on values that I find in each record.  Then I'm trying to increment the first value in the array based on the presence of another field in the record.

My problem occurs in the if statement when I check for the yes_or_no value.  When the second line incrementing dictionary2 is present in this statement, the value in dictionary 1 is incremented by the same value.  I have no idea why this is the case.

Please let me know if this isn't entirely clear.  Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: I don't understand. The code inside the `if` statement clearly increments elements in both dictionaries by the same amount (`row["a_number"]`). What are you expecting it to do?

Comment: Also, you should evaluate `row1["value1"].ToString().Trim()` once near the top of the `foreach` block and cache it in a local variable (likewise for value2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the values in both dictionary entries point to the same instance of `numbers`. This means any change to one will affect the other.

To put a new instance in each dictionary you could do something similar to:

```
...
if (!dictionary1.ContainsKey(row1["value1"].ToString().Trim()))
{
    dictionary1.Add(row1["value1"].ToString().Trim(), GetNumbersArray());
}
if (!dictionary2.ContainsKey(row1["value2"].ToString().Trim()))
{
     dictionary2.Add(row1["value2"].ToString().Trim(), GetNumbersArray());
}
...

private int[] GetNumbersArray()
{
    int[] numbers = new int[3];

    numbers[0] = 0;
    numbers[1] = 0;
    numbers[2] = 0;

    return numbers;
}
```

Comment: This was exactly the problem.  Solution worked perfectly.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You're adding a pointer to the array to each dictionary. Both dictionaries look at the same array, so when you modify the array through dictionary2, dictionary1 sees the changes.